# Insert record into table from selected option in dropdown-box

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and what i am trying to achieve is to insert a record into a table based on the selected option from a select element in a form where the options are the tables itself.

***PHP:***

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "inserir")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ['tabela'] (imagem, hipermercado, departamento, descricao, `desc`, tipo_desc, preco_ant, preco_desc, validade) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['imagemurl'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['hipermercado'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['departamento'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['descricao'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['desc'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['tipo_desc'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['preco_ant'], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['preco_desc'], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['validade'], "text"));
  mysql_select_db($database_promocaototal, $promocaototal);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $promocaototal) or die(mysql_error());
```

***HTML:***

```
<select name="table" id="table" style="color:#000000; font-size:16px">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>table1</option>
      <option>table2</option>
    </select>
```

Basically replace the table name in the php code by the selected option ie "table1" or "table2" is this possible? Many thanks.

Comment: First off that's not `PHP`, that's `SQL`.  Where is your PHP?

Comment: Can you include your `PHP` code please

Comment: You haven't set a `value` for the `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're missing the link on how to get the dropdown information to your PHP script if I understand you correctly.

Try using [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp), with `action=yourscript.php`. With submitting the form (e.g. by a button, as describe in the tutorial), you can grab the input in `yourscript.php` with the `$_GET["variableName"]` [variable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). Make sure to sanitize your input to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: As said, you also better set a `value` for the `<option>` tags.

Comment: <select name="tabela" id="tabela" style="color:#000000; font-size:16px">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option value="table1">table1</option>
          <option value="table2">table2</option>
        </select>` i did change but still no joy...

Comment: repat thats exactly what i am trying to find... the missing link you are correct.